# how to make my python framework to work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hive

I have a requirement where I need to create a `python` framework to load the existing `csv` file to a `hive` table. The original code that I have received was to first convert an `excel` sheet to `csv` and then load to the `hive` table. However, I have make changes in the existing code to read the existing `csv` and load to `hive`. Below is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os
import json
import re
import csv
import logging
import traceback
from datetime import datetime
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def getDateTime(fmt):
    ''' Get current date time in the specified format '''
    current_time = datetime.now()
    return current_time.strftime(fmt)


def initLogging(logFilePath):
    ''' Initializes Logging '''
    logFileName = "csvToHive_" + getDateTime(fmt="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+".log"
    if not (os.path.exists(logFilePath)):
        os.makedirs(logFilePath, 0775)
    global logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s:%(message)s',
                        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', filename=logFilePath+'/'+logFileName)


def getSrcFileNames(srcFilePath, regExForFileName):
    ''' get list of fileNames from srcFilePath using provided regular expression '''
    status = -1
    fileNamesList = []
    if os.path.exists(srcFilePath):
        status = 0
        regex = re.compile(regExForFileName, re.IGNORECASE)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(srcFilePath):
            for File in files:
                result = regex.findall(File)
                if result:
                    fileNamesList.append(result[0])
    return fileNamesList, status


def archiveFiles(srcFilePath, srcFileName, targetPath):
    ''' archive the files to the targetPath and append datetime to the file '''
    logging.info("Archiving File")
    if not (os.path.exists(targetPath)):
        os.makedirs(targetPath, 0770)

    fileNamewoExtn = srcFileName.split(".")[0]
    fileNameExtnList = srcFileName.split(".")[1:]
    fileNameExtn = ".".join(fileNameExtnList)
    destFileName = fileNamewoExtn + "-" + getDateTime(fmt="%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + "." + fileNameExtn
    strCommand = "mv \"" + srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName + "\" \"" + targetPath + "/" + destFileName + "\""
    logging.info(strCommand)
    archiveSubProcess = Popen(strCommand, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    archive_err = archiveSubProcess.communicate()[1]
    return archive_err


def remove_quotes(string):
    ''' This function removes the quotes from the string passed to this function'''
    return ''.join(c for c in string if c not in ('"', "'"))


def remove_alphanumeric(string):
    ''' This function removes alpha-numeric characters from the string passed to this function '''
    return ''.join(e for e in string if e.isalnum())


def loadCSVFileToHiveTable(csvFilesGeneratedList):
    status = 0
    with open(configFile) as json_data:
        config = json.load(json_data)
    for csvFile in csvFilesGeneratedList:
        logging.info("--------------------------------------------")
        print("\n")
        logging.info("Loading CSV File - %s into Hive Table" % csvFile)
        print("Loading CSV File", csvFile, "into Hive Table")
        configFound = False
        for csv_hive in config["CSVFileToHiveTable"]:
            if csv_hive['csvSheetName'] in csvFile:
                csvSheetName = csv_hive['csvSheetName']
                hiveDB_TableName = csv_hive['hiveDB_TableName']
                fieldsTerminated_by = csv_hive['fieldsTerminated_by']
                hiveTableHDFSLocation = csv_hive['hiveTableHDFSLocation']
                configFound = True
                break

        if configFound == False:
            logging.error("No Hive Configurations found for CSV File - %s" % csvFile)
            print("No Hive Configurations found for CSV File -", csvFile)
        else:
            with open(csvFile, 'rb') as fin:
                csvin = csv.reader(fin)
                headerRec = next(csvin, [])
            hiveSchema = ", ".join([col + " string" for col in headerRec])
            hiveDDL = "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + hiveDB_TableName + " (" + hiveSchema + " )"
            hiveDDL += " row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' "
            # hiveDDL +=  " row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' "
            hiveDDL += " with serdeproperties ('field.delim' = '" + fieldsTerminated_by + "') "
            hiveDDL += "STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '" + hiveTableHDFSLocation + "' "
            hiveDDL += "tblproperties ('skip.header.line.count'='1','orc.compress'='SNAPPY');"

            dropCommand = "hive -S -e \"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + hiveDB_TableName + "\";"
            logging.info("Drop existing Hive Table command - %s" % dropCommand)
            print("Dropping Hive Table", hiveDB_TableName)
            Popen(dropCommand, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()

            createCommand = "hive -S -e \"" + hiveDDL + "\""
            logging.info("Create Table Command - %s" % createCommand)
            print("Creating Hive Table", hiveDB_TableName)
            createSubProcess = Popen(createCommand, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
            err = createSubProcess.communicate()[1]
            retCode = createSubProcess.returncode
            if retCode != 0:
                print("Error in creating Hive Table.. Please check logs")
                logging.error("Error in creating Hive Table..")
                logging.error(err)
                print("Data Load Failed for Excel Sheet", csvSheetName)
                logging.error("Data Load Failed for Excel Sheet - %s" % csvSheetName)
                status += 1
            else:
                loadCommand = "hive -S -e \"LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '" + csvFile + "' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE " \
                              + hiveDB_TableName + ";\""
                logging.info("Load Data into Hive Table command - %s" % loadCommand)
                loadSubProcess = Popen(loadCommand, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
                err = loadSubProcess.communicate()[1]
                retCode = loadSubProcess.returncode
                if retCode != 0:
                    print("Error in Loading CSV File into Hive Table.. Please check logs")
                    logging.error("Error in Loading CSV File into Hive Table..")
                    logging.error(err)
                    print("Data Load Failed for Excel Sheet", csvSheetName)
                    logging.error("Data Load Failed for Excel Sheet - %s" % csvSheetName)
                    status += 1
                else:
                    print("Successfully Loaded CSV File into Hive Table", hiveDB_TableName)
                    logging.info("Successfully Loaded CSV File - %s into Hive Table - %s" % (csvFile, hiveDB_TableName))
                    logging.info("Archiving CSV File - %s archive path - %s" % (csvFile, archiveBasePath))
                    archive_err = archiveFiles("/".join(csvFile.split("/")[:-1]), csvFile.split("/")[-1],
                                               archiveBasePath)

        logging.info("--------------------------------------------")
    return status


def processConfig(configFile):
    exitCode = 0
    with open(configFile) as json_data:
        config = json.load(json_data)
        logFilePath = config["logFilePath"]

        # initialize Logging
        initLogging(logFilePath)
        logging.info("PROCESS STARTED")

        for csvFileSource in config["csvFileSource"]:
            srcFilePath = csvFileSource['sourceFilePath']
            regExForSrcFileName = csvFileSource['regExForSrcFileName']
            targetPath = csvFileSource['targetPath']
            workSheetsToExport = csvFileSource['workSheetsToExport']
            global archiveBasePath
            archiveBasePath = csvFileSource["archiveBasePath"]

            if not os.path.exists(targetPath):
                os.makedirs(targetPath, 0777)

            srcFileNamesList, status = getSrcFileNames(srcFilePath, regExForSrcFileName)
            if status == 0:
                if len(srcFileNamesList)!= 0:
                    for srcFileName in srcFileNamesList:
                        logging.info("********************************************")
                        logging.info("Processing File: %s" % (srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName))
                        logging.info("********************************************")

                        process_status, csvFilesGeneratedList = processExcelFile(
                            srcFile=srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName, targetPath=targetPath,
                            workSheetsToExport=workSheetsToExport)

                        # archive files
                        if process_status == 0:
                            logging.info("Successfully Converted Excel File: %s to CSV File(s)" % (
                                        srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName))
                            if archiveBasePath is not None:
                                archive_err = archiveFiles(srcFilePath, srcFileName, archiveBasePath)
                                if not archive_err:
                                    logging.info("Archived File: %s to Location: %s" % (
                                    srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName, archiveBasePath))
                                else:
                                    logging.error("Failed to Archive File: %s" % (srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName))
                                    exitCode += 1
                            else:
                                logging.info("Skipping Archiving File: %s" % (srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName))
                        else:
                            logging.error(
                                "Failed to Convert Excel File: %s to CSV File(s)" % (srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName))
                            logging.error("Skipping Archiving File: %s" % (srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName))
                            exitCode += 1
                        logging.info("********************************************")

                        logging.info("********************************************")
                        logging.info("Loading the generated CSV files into Hive Tables")
                        logging.info("Excel File : %s" % srcFileName)
                        logging.info("Generated CSV Files : %s" % csvFilesGeneratedList)
                        exitCode += loadCSVFileToHiveTable(csvFilesGeneratedList)
                        logging.info("Loading Files Completed")

                else:
                    logging.warn("No File found with RegEx %s in Path %s" % (regExForSrcFileName, srcFilePath))
                    exitCode += 1
            else:
                logging.error("Path: %s does not Exist" % (srcFilePath))
                exitCode += 1

        return exitCode


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Please pass json config file", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)

    global configFile
    configFile = str(sys.argv[1])

    exitCode = processConfig(configFile)

    logging.info("Program Exit Code: %s" % exitCode)
    logging.info("PROCESS ENDED")

    if exitCode != 0:
        sys.exit(exitCode)
```

The problem I am facing is within the function called `def processConfig`. In the original code there was a function called `def processExcelFile`, this function converted each and every workbook from an `excel` sheet to a `csv` file and load to the `hive`. However, in the current scenario, I do not have the importance of the function `def processExcelFile` as we already have the `csv` file available.  Anyway, coming back to `def processConfig`, there is a line as below within the function

```
process_status,csvFilesGeneratedList=processExcelFile(srcFile=srcFilePath + "/" + srcFileName, targetPath=targetPath,workSheetsToExport=workSheetsToExport)
```

When I am erasing the line, I am getting `unresolved reference` error on the very next line written with in the function `def processConfig`.
I am trying hard to put some logic to get this thing work. I hope that I was able to explain my issue. Please let me know if there is anything of my issue undescribed, I will try my best to explain them further.

Please suggest? Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you're not using Spark or Dask? Spark can simply be `spark.csv('file.csv').saveAsTable('data')`, which writes straight to Hive

Comment: I guess that should also work...But the code that I have posted here is the standard with my client. Can't help. A customer is always right.